# Problems booting Ubuntu 10.10 with Nvdia GeForce 6600gt

Tags: nvidia, gpu, lockup

I am quite new to Ubuntu and I already stumbled upon a problem. I run Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat now and Install went fine, when trying to boot the screen popped black and I faced this message "gpu lockup - switching to software fbcon." When setting the display to onboard VGA through BIOS Ubuntu has no problem at all, but when I switch back to my AGP card (which is a Nvidia GeForce 6600GT) I get that message again. I do not use VGA for that card I use my DVI cable for it. Does anyone have an answer for me to make this work? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Install the nvidia driver by running this command on the terminal

> sudo jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_current

reboot.

Comment: Do I have to download something or do I just imput that command into the console? And if download is needed can you give me the proper link? Nvidia GeForce 6600GT APG and using DVI.

Comment: No need to download. Just type the line in the terminal. that would be enough.